# Time series returns co-factorization over multiple periods

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, plyr, finance

I want to cumulate the returns of >4000 individual securities over 3 months i.e. a quarter. I want the results in a new dataframe showing what the cumulative returns are per quarter. How can I do this in a loop or using the apply function/plyr package?

Example:

```
returns<-c(rnorm(96,1,0.1))
    names<-c(rep("a",24),rep("b",24),rep("c",24), rep("d",24))
    years<-c(rep(2003,12),rep(2004,12))
    year<-rep(years,4)
    month<-rep(1:12,8)
    funds<-data.frame(names,year,month,returns)
```

EDIT:

I have written the following code previously (for my real dataset)

```
for (k in 1:length(uniquefundnames)){                               

  id<-funds$id[k]                                   

  quart1<-period.1$factor.perf[period.1$fund_id==id]*           
    period.2$factor.perf[period.2$fund_id==id]*
    period.3$factor.perf[period.3$fund_id==id]

 funds$return.1[k]<-quart1                          

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do something? If so, show us what have you tried and tell us what part of your code didn't work ;)

Comment: Thanks Jilber, just added it above. As you can tell it's a copy and paste method and I'm looking to write an actual loop or a plyr function that circles through the different funds, years, and months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this with plyr:

```
require(plyr)
funds$q<-ceiling(funds$month/3)
ddply(funds,.(year,q),summarize,ret=prod(returns))

  year q      ret
1 2003 1 1.349575
2 2003 2 1.156997
3 2003 3 1.094396
4 2003 4 1.114892
5 2004 1 1.205335
6 2004 2 1.086034
7 2004 3 1.468498
8 2004 4 1.833158
```

**EDIT** - sorry - cumulative by name

```
require(plyr)
funds$q<-ceiling(funds$month/3)
qrets<-ddply(funds,.(names,year,q),summarize,ret=prod(returns))
qrets$cum<-cumprod(qrets$ret)



names year q       ret      cum
1      a 2003 1 1.0561211 1.056121
2      a 2003 2 1.0953151 1.156785
3      a 2003 3 1.0216484 1.181828
4      a 2003 4 0.9917425 1.172069
5      a 2004 1 1.0119346 1.186057
6      a 2004 2 1.2291385 1.457829
7      a 2004 3 1.1856941 1.728539
8      a 2004 4 1.1645479 2.012966
9      b 2003 1 0.9441853 1.900613
10     b 2003 2 1.0018355 1.904102
11     b 2003 3 1.0503731 2.000017
12     b 2003 4 0.9353941 1.870804
13     b 2004 1 1.0605124 1.984011
14     b 2004 2 0.9882635 1.960726
15     b 2004 3 0.9051943 1.774838
16     b 2004 4 0.9547135 1.694462
17     c 2003 1 1.1991934 2.031987
18     c 2003 2 1.2028025 2.444079
19     c 2003 3 1.2238102 2.991089
20     c 2003 4 0.9579562 2.865332
21     c 2004 1 1.0398172 2.979422
22     c 2004 2 0.9187201 2.737255
23     c 2004 3 1.1507847 3.149991
24     c 2004 4 1.2836914 4.043617
25     d 2003 1 1.1285913 4.563591
26     d 2003 2 0.8766021 4.000453
27     d 2003 3 0.8333271 3.333686
28     d 2003 4 1.2545656 4.182328
29     d 2004 1 1.0801464 4.517526
30     d 2004 2 0.9731656 4.396301
31     d 2004 3 1.1889534 5.226997
32     d 2004 4 1.2844251 6.713686
```

**EDIT** updated with treatment of partial quarter data and filtering for subsets of names

```
require(plyr)
funds$q<-ceiling(funds$month/3)
qrets<-ddply(funds,.(names,year,q),summarize,ret=prod(returns),no_months=length(names))

# options for quarters with missing months (only pick one)
qrets$cum<-cumprod(qrets[qrets$no_months==3,]$ret)  # ignores entire quarter
qrets$cum<-cumprod(qrets$ret*3/qrets$no_months)     # factor the existing performanc
                                                    # to the entire quarter


qrets                                      # returns all results
qrets[qrets$names %in% c("a","b"),]        # filters for a subset of names

names year q       ret no_months      cum
1      a 2003 1 1.1791380         3 1.179138
2      a 2003 2 1.0300797         3 1.214606
3      a 2003 3 0.9737514         3 1.182724
4      a 2003 4 0.9431317         3 1.115465
5      a 2004 1 0.9750367         3 1.087619
6      a 2004 2 1.2181052         3 1.324835
7      a 2004 3 0.9239893         3 1.224133
8      a 2004 4 0.9864147         3 1.207503
9      b 2003 1 1.2407158         3 1.498168
10     b 2003 2 0.9369874         3 1.403765
11     b 2003 3 0.7991036         3 1.121753
12     b 2003 4 1.1315174         3 1.269283
13     b 2004 1 0.9563123         3 1.213831
14     b 2004 2 0.9895436         3 1.201139
15     b 2004 3 1.2702817         3 1.525785
16     b 2004 4 0.8010484         3 1.222228
```

Comment: Troy, THANK YOU!! How would you split the results into separate dataframes by another variable (e.g. industry type) For example, securities a and b, and securities b, c, d, in two seperate data.frames. e.g. dlply then ddply doesn't work

Comment: Is there a way to ignore the quarter returns if there are less than three months e.g. Jan, Feb, no March. Now the code assigns Jan and Feb as quarterly returns even ifthe series is incomplete.

Comment: Hi - those options are added in the answer

Comment: Thank you so much Troy.. I hope you see this!